# How to Convert T-SQL IF statement to Databricks PySpark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have the following code in T-SQL

```
IF NOT EXISTS (   SELECT     *   FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   WHERE     TABLE_NAME = 'airports' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'airport_region') SELECT * FROM airports;
```

I would like to convert the above T-SQL to Pyspark.

I have the following dataframe

```
df = df1.createOrReplaceTempView('airports')
```

My attempt at converting the above is as follows:

```
sql("""IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM airports  where table = airports and COLUMN = 'airport_region') select * from airports""")
```

The above gives me a ParseException: error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that `df1` is your airports dataset and you only want to do something with it if it does not contain the column 'airport_region'? If so you can simply do `if not 'airport_region' in df1.columns: <do stuff>`. If not, then some further clarification would be good.

Comment: Hi @ScootCork, could you provide a full example? I'm a little confused

Comment: Hi @ScootCork, I'm still getting the ParseException error after attempting your suggestion.

Comment: I also tried ```sql("""IF NOT EXISTS 'airport_region' in airports.COLUMNS select * from airports""")``` but I still get ParseException error

Comment: @Patterson, you want the above normal SQL query to be run as pyspark query or only as Databricks SQL query?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, ideally I would like PySpark query, but I would be equally happy with Databricks SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the above and if you want to do it in Pyspark you can use the above query and inside if, execute the SQL script.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("sample1")
if('name1' not in df.columns):
    spark.sql("select * from sample1").show()
```

[image]

If you want to do it in SQL query you can try like below.

First get the columns names as dataframe and save as a temporary view and using that view, if the your column name not exists in that select the required table.

```
column_names=spark.sql("show columns in sample1");
column_names.createOrReplaceTempView("tempcols")
spark.sql("select * from sample1 where not exists (select * from tempcols where col_name='name1')").show()
```

[image]

**If column exists:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, thanks again for reaching out. Going to try your suggestion now....

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, when I enter the following ```spark.sql("select * from sample1 where not exists (select * from tempcols where col_name='name1')").show()``` I get the error *col_name* doesn't exists. If I change *col_name* to COLUMN I get the error COLUMN doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, I have just finished up testing your solution, and I want to say another big thanks to you. I decided to go with your PySpark suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if('airport_region' not in df1.columns):
    <do stuff>
```

Comment: Hi @ARCrow, using your suggestion I did the following ```sql(""""if('airport_region' not in df1.columns) select * from df1""")``` but I still get ParseException error

Comment: Any more thoughts SO?

Comment: @Patterson why are you wrapping everything in a spark.sql api? My code is in python not sql.